# If I use the system() function in php and the command contains a password, how unsafe is that?

Tags: php, security, unix, passwords

I have a php script which generates a report. The end user of this report wants it uploaded to a server where they can access it. I have an account with SFTP access to upload files to their server.

One way to do this would be to call

```
system("lftp -e ... -u user,password sftp://host");
```

I know that it is usually unsafe to provide a password on the command line, since other users can see command lines with programs like w and ps.

Since this is done from the php process, is this any different or just as unsafe?

Obviously using CURL or another library to do the SFTP connection would be safest and the "right way" to do it. This question is for my education on this particular issue, so I don't need anyone to tell me to use curl instead. The ftp example is just an example.

Comment: It's no different. A shell exec from PHP will work essentially the same as a user typing that command manually, and your password will show up in a ps list. (At least for lftp.) Some programs (like ncftp and curl) will adjust their own command line, overwriting the user/pass with dummy chars.

Comment: @Alex: Is it legal/portable to overwrite the contents of `argv`?  Can you depend on that behavior across platforms?

Comment: The C standard seems to indicate that it's portable. However, its use certainly isn't consistent, and I'd never recommend relying on it in a security context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can think of 3 potential problems:

- visible using ps (just as from console)
- may be (not sure if really is) stored in shell history which means, on hdd (just as from console)
- if you keep password in your source file instead of keeping it in variable then it's also in VCS (different than from console)